# Is it possible to deploy a docker hub publicly hosted image to Kubernetes Container Engine without uploading it to Containers Registery?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Still new to Containers and Kubernetes here but I am dabbling with deploying a cluster on Google Containers Engine and was wondering if you can use a docker hub hosted image to deploy containers, so in my .yaml configuration file I'd say:

```
  ...
  image: hub.docker.com/r/my-team/my-image:latest
  ...
```

Is this possible? Or one has to download/build image locally and then upload it to Google Containers Registery?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The Replication Controller template or Pod spec image isn't special. If you specify `image: redis` you will get the latest tag of the official Docker Hub library Redis image, just as if you did `docker pull redis`.

Comment: I haven't tried this out yet but thanks I wasn't sure it would be able to pull it from docker registery :-)

Comment: I used an image from the public hub as well, docker ps on the Container-Optimized Google Compute Engine shows the running image but I can not access it via the exposed external IP or my projects <project-id>.appspot.com endpoint. Am I missing something? This should probably be another question.

Comment: how can you specify a specific version?

Comment: hi how will you add image link of public repository , that is witout pulling the image locally add to container the link of public repo. Or simply how will you able to create a public link of repository such as http://index.io.something of my public repo